# Can I travel within the US using only my foreign passport as ID?

Tags: usa, airlines, passports

I want to know if I can travel with my passport within the US being in immigration process?
I will be okay using only my passport ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand your question.  Are you wanting to travel domestically in the US, using your passport as your only form of ID?

Comment: Yes, because i have immigration courts but i wanna know if i can travel like visit another state without me having some type US IDs or a driver license the passport i have right now is from my country though? I want to know if i can still travel within the US only using my passport as my only ID?

Comment: What passport (country) do you have?  And are you only flying?

Comment: Salvadorian passport, yes i want to go on vacations with my friends. I want to know if its possible to travel or i will have any problems at the airport ?

Comment: @Alex. Were you able to fly with just you passport?.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For travel in the US (which I did in April) you only need your passport as a form of ID.  This is for the immigration process (you'll need a visa, most likely, in your passport), and for all internal flights as well.

It *is* possible to fly internally without a passport as a foreigner, as an English friend did in April as well, but it was VERY difficult, as every security person expects you to have your passport available to travel with.

Comment: @MarkMayo: What did your friend use in terms of ID?

Comment: @Jonas he had a UK driver's license and his printed tickets, and is a salesman ;)

Comment: "but it was VERY difficult" No it isn't. You just need an accepted form of ID. The problem with your friend was that he did not have any accepted form of ID besides his passport. Foreign driver's license is not an accepted form of ID for the TSA (http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/acceptable-ids). However, if he had a U.S. driver's license or state ID, or green card, he would not need a passport.

Comment: @user102008, yes, thus "it was VERY difficult" for him.  Note that the question is about foreigners, not US citizens.

Comment: @MarkMayo: yes, I was talking about foreigners. You don't need to be a U.S. citizen to get a driver's license or state ID. You just need to be in the U.S. for a while.

Comment: Yes, and most foreigners in the US will be visitors. Tourists.  Getting a driver's license is not really an option for them.

Comment: Pro tip: If you're going to buy alcohol at all it's worth it to carry around an additional form of photo ID, e.g driver's license or student card. I get carded in the US all the time even though I don't look young at all. You don't want to risk carrying your passport around when you go out just so you can buy a drink

Comment: Note that according to user102008's TSA link, Canadian provincial driver's licenses are acceptable ID for that subclass of foreigner.